# Remove repeated "Theorem (" in the list of theorems

Tags: environments, amsthm, thmtools

I use `declaretheoremstyle` to define a theorem environment, and print a list of theorems in the end of my document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=6pt, spacebelow=6pt,
headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
postheadspace=1em,
notefont=\bfseries,
notebraces={(}{)},
bodyfont=\itshape,
shaded={bgcolor=yellow!20}
]{thmstyle}

\declaretheorem[style=thmstyle,name=Theorem]{theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[name]
...
\end{theorem}

\renewcommand{\listtheoremname}{List of Theorems}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listtheoremname}
\listoftheorems[ignoreall,show=theorem]

\end{document}
```

The list of theorems is printed in the end (please ignore the font color):

[image]

Now, the problem is how to print directly the name of the theorems, instead of repeating always "Theorem("?

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\thmt@mklistcmd
  {\thmt@thmname}
  {\check@optarg{\thmt@thmname}}
  {}{}
\patchcmd\thmt@mklistcmd
  {\thmt@thmname\ifx}
  {\check@optarg{\thmt@thmname}\ifx}
  {}{}
\protected\def\check@optarg#1{%
  \@ifnextchar\thmtformatoptarg\@secondoftwo{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\declaretheoremstyle[
  spaceabove=6pt, spacebelow=6pt,
  headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
  postheadspace=1em,
  notefont=\bfseries,
  notebraces={(}{)},
  bodyfont=\itshape,
  shaded={bgcolor=yellow!20}
]{thmstyle}

\declaretheorem[style=thmstyle,name=Theorem]{theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Somebody]
...
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
...
\end{theorem}

\renewcommand{\listtheoremname}{List of Theorems}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listtheoremname}
\listoftheorems[ignoreall,show=theorem]

\end{document}
```

[image]