# How to create function that creates definitions and is formatted in a certain way

Tags: macros, formatting

I'm new to LaTeX macros and am hoping to create a command that definitions a function called "definition". When I use `\definition{}`, it would automatically format whatever is in `{}` to be bold, on a new line, and followed by colon. So it would look like this:

So it would look like this:

**definition 1**: blah blah blah

**definition 2**: blah blah blah

**definition 3**: blah blah blah

And then would there be a way to list all of the definitions at the end of the doc by calling on `\definition{}`?

Thanks!

Comment: This is something like a `\newtheorem` etc. with packages `amsthm`, `thmtools`, `tcolorbox`, `mdframed`, the later can produce lists of theorems etc.

Comment: Maybe helpful https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249980/124842 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45821/124842.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You need to use `environ` package to define a new listing environment in the way you want. In the preamble use the following syntax:

```
\NewEnviron{definition}[Numer of Inputs][Default Option]
{%
    \begin{enumerate}[\textbf{#1} \bfseries #2:]
        \BODY
    \end{enumerate}
}
```

You can then use the syntax: `\begin{definition}[Your Definition]{Numbering Format}` to begin an environment.

Note that `Default Option` defines the first option (`#1`) in the definition above and if you used `\begin{definition}{numbering format}` and the predefined code above will put "Default Option" for the name of listing.

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{paralist}


\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{definition}[2][Definition]
{%
    \begin{enumerate}[\textbf{#1} \bfseries #2:]
        \BODY
    \end{enumerate}
}



\begin{document}


\begin{definition}[Custom Definition]{1}
    \item First entry
    \item Second entry
    \item Third entry
\end{definition}


\end{document}
```